# Rails namespaced models give uninitialized constant errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces

I have two models in namespace `project` like this: `class Project::Foo` and `class Project::Bar`

They have this relationship

in `app/models/project/foo.rb` `has_many :bars`

in `app/models/project/bar.rb` `belongs_to :foo`

However when I want to call `Project::Foo.create(...)` or even `Project::Bar.create(...)` I get a `NameError` with `uninitialized constant Foo` or `Bar` respectively.

Do I need to put something like this in the models? `belongs_to :project::foo`? or how do I fix this?

EDIT

in `app/models/project/foo.rb` now reads:

```
module Project
  class Foo
    has_many :bars
  end
end
```

and bars has the same structure but with the `belongs_to` in it

I still get the same error

Comment: Do you get the error if you remove the `belongs_to` and `has_many` relationships?

Comment: Are your models inheriting from ActiveRecord?  I don't think you can use the relationship macros w/o that.  So if you change your class definition to `class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base` (inside your module def)?

Comment: no they do not (am not using AR), however inside the class they use `include Mongoid::Document`. This used to work fine before the namespacing.

Comment: Seeing it was Mongoid that has the issue, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211962/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-namespaces-and-reference-models-inheriting-from-ot) fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have class Foo, code within the file should look

```
module Project #create the scope
  class Foo

  end
end
```

or you may, define file project.rb with

```
module Project
end
```

and keep related models in project folder

Comment: You are running this code from console (`rails console`) or via running server?

Comment: If from console... try to restart it.

Comment: i restarted the server. The error persists. When I remove the association, it works fine. Why?